# Differences between different attention layers for Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, attention-model

I am trying to add an attention layer for my text classification model. The inputs are texts (e.g. movie review), the output is a binary outcome (e.g. positive vs negative).

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 32, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Bidirectional(CuDNNGRU(16,return_sequences=True)))
##### add attention layer here #####
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

After some searching, I found a couple of read-to-use attention layers for keras. There is the `keras.layers.Attention` layer that is built-in in Keras. There is also the `SeqWeightedAttention` and `SeqSelfAttention layer` in the keras-self-attention package. As a person who is relatively new to the deep learning field, I have a hard time understanding the mechanism behind these layers.

What does each of these lays do? Which one will be the best for my model?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RNN, I would not recommend using the keras.layers.Attention class.

While analysing tf.keras.layers.Attention Github code to better understand how to use the same, the first line I could come across was - "This class is suitable for Dense or CNN networks, and not for RNN networks"

There is another open source version maintained by CyberZHG called
keras-self-attention. To the best of my knowledge this is NOT a part of the Keras or TensorFlow library and seems to be an independent piece of code. This contains the two classes you mentioned -  SeqWeightedAttention & SeqSelfAttention layer classes. former returns a 2D value and latter a 3D value. So the SeqWeightedAttention should work for your situation. The former seems to be loosely based on Raffel et al and can be used for Seq classification, The latter seems to be a variation of Bahdanau.

In general, I would suggest you to write your own seq to classification model. The attention piece can be added in less than half a dozen lines of code (bare-bones essence)...much less than the time you would spend in integrating or debugging or understanding the code in these external libraries.

Please refer: [Create an LSTM layer with Attention in Keras for multi-label text classification neural network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060083/create-an-lstm-layer-with-attention-in-keras-for-multi-label-text-classification/64853996#64853996)

Comment: It would be better if you can address the OP's question by also explaining the purpose for each layer too.

Comment: Edited my answer to better address OPs query