# Create an LSTM layer with Attention in Keras for multi-label text classification neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Greetings dear members of the community. I am creating a neural network to predict a multi-label y. Specifically, the neural network takes 5 inputs (list of actors, plot summary, movie features, movie reviews, title) and tries to predict the sequence of movie genres. In the neural network I use Embeddings Layer and Global Max Pooling layers.

However, I recently discovered the Recurrent Layers with Attention, which are a very interesting topic these days in machine learning translation. So, I wondered if I could use one of those layers but only the Plot Summary input. Note that I don't do ml translation but rather text classification.

My neural network in its current state

```py
def create_fit_keras_model(hparams,
                           version_data_control,
                           optimizer_name,
                           validation_method,
                           callbacks,
                           optimizer_version = None):

    sentenceLength_actors = X_train_seq_actors.shape[1]
    vocab_size_frequent_words_actors = len(actors_tokenizer.word_index)

    sentenceLength_plot = X_train_seq_plot.shape[1]
    vocab_size_frequent_words_plot = len(plot_tokenizer.word_index)

    sentenceLength_features = X_train_seq_features.shape[1]
    vocab_size_frequent_words_features = len(features_tokenizer.word_index)

    sentenceLength_reviews = X_train_seq_reviews.shape[1]
    vocab_size_frequent_words_reviews = len(reviews_tokenizer.word_index)

    sentenceLength_title = X_train_seq_title.shape[1]
    vocab_size_frequent_words_title = len(title_tokenizer.word_index)

    model = keras.Sequential(name='{0}_{1}dim_{2}batchsize_{3}lr_{4}decaymultiplier_{5}'.format(sequential_model_name, 
                                                                                                str(hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM]), 
                                                                                                str(hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS]),
                                                                                                str(hparams[HP_LEARNING_RATE]), 
                                                                                                str(hparams[HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER]),
                                                                                                version_data_control))
    actors = keras.Input(shape=(sentenceLength_actors,), name='actors_input')
    plot = keras.Input(shape=(sentenceLength_plot,), batch_size=hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS], name='plot_input')
    features = keras.Input(shape=(sentenceLength_features,), name='features_input')
    reviews = keras.Input(shape=(sentenceLength_reviews,), name='reviews_input')
    title = keras.Input(shape=(sentenceLength_title,), name='title_input')

    emb1 = layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size_frequent_words_actors + 2,
                            output_dim = 16, #hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM], hyperparametered or fixed sized.
                            embeddings_initializer = 'uniform',
                            mask_zero = True,
                            input_length = sentenceLength_actors,
                            name="actors_embedding_layer")(actors)
    
    # encoded_layer1 = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(name="globalaveragepooling_actors_layer")(emb1)
    encoded_layer1 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(name="globalmaxpooling_actors_layer")(emb1)
    
    emb2 = layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size_frequent_words_plot + 2,
                            output_dim = hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM],
                            embeddings_initializer = 'uniform',
                            mask_zero = True,
                            input_length = sentenceLength_plot,
                            name="plot_embedding_layer")(plot)
    # (Option 1)
    # encoded_layer2 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(name="globalmaxpooling_plot_summary_Layer")(emb2)
 
    # (Option 2)
    emb2 = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM], return_sequences=True))(emb2)
    avg_pool = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(emb2)
    max_pool = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(emb2)
    conc = layers.concatenate([avg_pool, max_pool])

    # (Option 3)
    # emb2 = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM], return_sequences=True))(emb2)
    # emb2 = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM], return_sequences=True))(emb2)
    # emb2 = AttentionWithContext()(emb2)

    emb3 = layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size_frequent_words_features + 2,
                            output_dim = hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM],
                            embeddings_initializer = 'uniform',
                            mask_zero = True,
                            input_length = sentenceLength_features,
                            name="features_embedding_layer")(features)
    
    # encoded_layer3 = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(name="globalaveragepooling_movie_features_layer")(emb3)
    encoded_layer3 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(name="globalmaxpooling_movie_features_layer")(emb3)
    
    emb4 = layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size_frequent_words_reviews + 2,
                            output_dim = hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM],
                            embeddings_initializer = 'uniform',
                            mask_zero = True,
                            input_length = sentenceLength_reviews,
                            name="reviews_embedding_layer")(reviews)
    
    # encoded_layer4 = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(name="globalaveragepooling_user_reviews_layer")(emb4)
    encoded_layer4 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(name="globalmaxpooling_user_reviews_layer")(emb4)

    emb5 = layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size_frequent_words_title + 2,
                            output_dim = hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM],
                            embeddings_initializer = 'uniform',
                            mask_zero = True,
                            input_length = sentenceLength_title,
                            name="title_embedding_layer")(title)
    
    # encoded_layer5 = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(name="globalaveragepooling_movie_title_layer")(emb5)
    encoded_layer5 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(name="globalmaxpooling_movie_title_layer")(emb5)

    merged = layers.concatenate([encoded_layer1, conc, encoded_layer3, encoded_layer4, encoded_layer5], axis=-1) #(Option 2)
    # merged = layers.concatenate([encoded_layer1, emb2, encoded_layer3, encoded_layer4, encoded_layer5], axis=-1) #(Option 3)

    dense_layer_1 = layers.Dense(hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS],
                                 kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(neural_network_parameters['l2_regularization']),
                                 activation=neural_network_parameters['dense_activation'],
                                 name="1st_dense_hidden_layer_concatenated_inputs")(merged)
    
    layers.Dropout(neural_network_parameters['dropout_rate'])(dense_layer_1)
    
    output_layer = layers.Dense(neural_network_parameters['number_target_variables'],
                                activation=neural_network_parameters['output_activation'],
                                name='output_layer')(dense_layer_1)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=[actors, plot, features, reviews, title], outputs=output_layer, name='{0}_{1}dim_{2}batchsize_{3}lr_{4}decaymultiplier_{5}'.format(sequential_model_name, 
                                                                                                                                                                  str(hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM]), 
                                                                                                                                                                  str(hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS]),
                                                                                                                                                                  str(hparams[HP_LEARNING_RATE]), 
                                                                                                                                                                  str(hparams[HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER]),
                                                                                                                                                                  version_data_control))
    print(model.summary())
    
#     pruning_schedule = tfmot.sparsity.keras.PolynomialDecay(initial_sparsity=0.0,
#                                                             final_sparsity=0.4,
#                                                             begin_step=600,
#                                                             end_step=1000)
    
#     model_for_pruning = tfmot.sparsity.keras.prune_low_magnitude(model, pruning_schedule=pruning_schedule)
    
    if optimizer_name=="adam" and optimizer_version is None:
        
        optimizer = optimizer_adam_v2(hparams)
        
    elif optimizer_name=="sgd" and optimizer_version is None:
        
        optimizer = optimizer_sgd_v1(hparams, "no decay")
        
    elif optimizer_name=="rmsprop" and optimizer_version is None:
        
        optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop_v1(hparams)

    print("here: {0}".format(optimizer.lr))

    lr_metric = [get_lr_metric(optimizer)]
    
    if type(get_lr_metric(optimizer)) in (float, int):

        print("Learning Rate's type is Float or Integer")
        model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                      loss=neural_network_parameters['model_loss'],
                      metrics=neural_network_parameters['model_metric'] + lr_metric, )
    else:
        print("Learning Rate's type is not Float or Integer, but rather {0}".format(type(lr_metric)))
        model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                      loss=neural_network_parameters['model_loss'],
                      metrics=neural_network_parameters['model_metric'], ) #+ lr_metric
```

You will see in the above structure that I have 5 input layers, 5 Embedding layers, then I apply a Bidirectional layer on LSTM only in the Plot Summary input.

However, with the current bidirectional approach on Plot summary, I got the following error. My problem is how I can utilize the attention in text classification and not solve the error below. So, don't comment solution on this error.

[image]

My question is about suggesting ways on how to create a recurrent layer with attention for the plot summary (input 2). Also, do not hesitate to write in comments any article that might help me on achieving this in Keras.

I remain at your disposal if any additional information is required regarding the structure of the neural network.

*If you find the above neural network complicated I can make a simple version of it. However, the above is my original neural network, so I want any proposals do be based on that nn.*

---

**EDIT: 14.12.2020**

Find [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OOT3ueAnLzJroNL-NUfztfQAZHzKt9NR?usp=sharing) the colab notebook with the code I want to execute. The code has included two answers, one proposed in the comments (from an already answered question, and the other written as an official answer to my question.

The first approach proposed by @MarcoCerliani works. Although, I would like also the second approach to work. The approach of @Allohvk (*both approaches are implemented in the Runtime cell [21] of the attached colab)*. The latter does not work at the moment. The latest error I get is:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer globalmaxpooling_plot_summary_Layer is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 100]

I solved the latest error of my edit by removing the `globalmaxpooling_plot_summary_Layer` from my neural's network structure.

Comment: here a simple way to add attention: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62949137/10375049

Comment: @MarcoCerliani ty for the answer. I will catch up with you later when I try your example. I will also post a Google Colab notebook with your approach and the one mentioned in the answer below. Thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: @MarcoCerliani I tested your approach and it worked for me. In your answer above you have also included a Google Colab notebook that was really helpful. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Here is one new feature in tensorflow. Currently finding examples but this might be an official implementation. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Attention

Comment: @krenerd Thanks a lot for the link. Indeed in any new version of Tensorflow new layers are added.  Google developers seem to search and look what is our struggle in SO. Glad that we have a website that inspires new development and upgrade of current tools that newcomers can easily digest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me summarize the intent. You want to add attention to your code. Yours is a sequence classification task and not a seq-seq translator. You dont really care much about the way it is done, so you are ok with not debugging the error above, but just need a working piece of code. Our main input here is the movie reviews consisting of 'n' words for which you want to add attention.

Assume you embed the reviews and pass it to an LSTM layer. Now you want to 'attend' to all the hidden states of the LSTM layer and then generate a classification (instead of just using the last hidden state of the encoder). So an attention layer needs to be inserted. A barebones implementation would look like this:

```
    def __init__(self):    
        ##Nothing special to be done here
        super(peel_the_layer, self).__init__()
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        ##Define the shape of the weights and bias in this layer
        ##This is a 1 unit layer. 
        units=1
        ##last index of the input_shape is the number of dimensions of the prev
        ##RNN layer. last but 1 index is the num of timesteps
        self.w=self.add_weight(name="att_weights", shape=(input_shape[-1], units), initializer="normal") #name property is useful for avoiding RuntimeError: Unable to create link.
        self.b=self.add_weight(name="att_bias", shape=(input_shape[-2], units), initializer="zeros")
        super(peel_the_layer,self).build(input_shape)
        
    def call(self, x):
        ##x is the input tensor..each word that needs to be attended to
        ##Below is the main processing done during training
        ##K is the Keras Backend import
        e = K.tanh(K.dot(x,self.w)+self.b)
        a = K.softmax(e, axis=1)
        output = x*a
        
        ##return the ouputs. 'a' is the set of attention weights
        ##the second variable is the 'attention adjusted o/p state' or context
        return a, K.sum(output, axis=1)
```

Now call the above Attention layer after your LSTM and before your Dense output layer.

```
        a, context = peel_the_layer()(lstm_out)
        ##context is the o/p which be the input to your classification layer
        ##a is the set of attention weights and you may want to route them to a display
```

You can build on top of this as you seem to want to use other features apart for the movie reviews to come up with the final sentiment. Attention largely applies to reviews..and benefits are to be seen if the sentences are very long.

For more specific details, please refer https://towardsdatascience.com/create-your-own-custom-attention-layer-understand-all-flavours-2201b5e8be9e

Comment: Allohvk thank you for your answer. I will try your approach in the next couple of days. Also I will post a Colab Notebook in order to review with you your answer. Keep in touch. Thanks

Comment: Allohvk, I am back after I have tested your answer and followed the link posted in towardsdatascience.com. Although I have a hard time figuring out an error in my approach. To have a better look at it please click on the colab notebook attached to my edited question.

Comment: I solved it by removing the ```global max pooling``` layer from my implementation. Although, I would like to use such a layer. What are your suggestions?

Comment: NikSp - Travelling and will revert to u in couple of days